# MS-Access form: Is it possible to create a Gantt chart and dynamic timeline?

Tags: ms-access, project-management, timeline, gantt-chart

I designed and maintained a database used to track my organizations projects. Access frontend with a SQL backend. I have a table for all the scheduling events. Task, Start, Finish, duration etc. Really basic. I am looking to create a form or report that displays a Gantt chart.
At the same time I'd also like to create what we call a Bird on Wire Chart. Not sure it that is a term unique to my group. It is a line divided up in months with triangles associated with events and dates. Project managers use power point to move the triangles around to show major milestones for their project. I'd like to automate this somehow using the data from the schedule table.

First is it possible to do these things? and second and example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

You didn't mention if you want to implement this in Access or some other client. If you are thinking of HTML or .NET client, then the RadiantQ Gantt components (http://www.radiantq.com) will help you implement what you are looking for (dynamic timelines and milestones among other things).

Here is an online demo of the RadiantQ jQuery Gantt:
http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm

Good luck with your project!